# Minimize shuffle spill and shuffle write

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, shuffle

I have following pipeline in HDFS which I am processing in spark

**input table :** `batch, team, user,  metric1, metric2`

This table can has user level metrics in hourly batches. In same hour a user can have multiple entries.

**level 1 aggregation :** this aggregation to get latest entry per user per batch

`agg(metric1) as user_metric1, agg(metric2) as user_metric2 (group by batch, team, user)`

**level 2 aggregation :** get team level metrics

`agg(user_metric1) as team_metric1, agg(user_metric2) as team_metric2 (group by batch, team)`

Input table is 8gb (snappy parquet format) in size in HDFS. My spark job is showing shuffle write to 40gb and at least 1 gb per executor shuffle spill.

In order to minimize this, if I repartition input table on user level before performaing aggregation,

```
df = df.repartition('user')
```

would it improve performance? How should I approach this problem if I want to reduce shuffle?

While running with following resources

```
spark.executor.cores=6
spark.cores.max=48
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=200
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark shuffles data from a node to another one because the resources is distributed (input data...) over the cluster, this can make the calculation slow and can present a heavy network traffic over the cluster, for your case the number of shuffles is due to the group by , if you make a repartition based on the three columns of the goup by it will reduce the number of shuffles, for the spark configuration the default spark.sql.shuffle.partitions is 200, let's say that we will let spark configuration as it is, the repartition will take some time and once finished the calculation will be faster:

```
new_df = df.repartition("batch","team", "user")
```